# Symfony 2 assetic error 500 using controller in dev mode, works fine dumping from CLI?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3, assetic

My server is a custom virtual server running CentOS x64, `node` installed and working. Assetic configuration:

```
assetic:
    use_controller: false
    node:           /usr/bin/node
    filters:
        less:
            node_paths: [/usr/lib/node_modules/]
```

When I access any page using a less filter I get the following error (content of CSS generated file):

```
exception] 500 | Internal Server Error | Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException
[message] The process has been signaled with signal &quot;11&quot;.
[1] Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException: The process has been signaled with signal &quot;11&quot;.
    at n/a
        in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.it/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php line 318

    at Symfony\Component\Process\Process-&gt;wait()
        in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.it/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php line 197

    at Symfony\Component\Process\Process-&gt;run()
        in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.it/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/LessFilter.php line 149

    at Assetic\Filter\LessFilter-&gt;filterLoad(object(FileAsset))
        in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.it/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/FilterCollection.php line 62

    at Assetic\Filter\FilterCollection-&gt;filterLoad(object(FileAsset))
        in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.it/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Asset/BaseAsset.php line 90

    at Assetic\Asset\BaseAsset-&gt;doLoad(&#039;@vendor-dir: &amp;quot;../../../../../vendor&amp;quot;;
```

However dumping assets using `php app/console assetic:dump --env=dev` works fine as expected. Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT**: I opened a issue [here](https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/issues/257).

Comment: Are you using APC or any other cache? They might be the cause of the segmentation fault. Try without one being enabled.

Comment: Not at all, fast cgi on the server so no point to use APC..

Comment: This looks like a permissions issue. Your web user may not have all the necessary access. Try `sudo su apache -s/bin/sh` or whatever your web server is running under and then run `app/console assetic:dump --env=dev`

Comment: Happens also in windows... i don't think it's a permission issue...

Comment: You want to use the controller generation with assetic but you've turned it off with `use_controller: false`.

Answer (score -2):

You may want to:

- clear your cache
- execute `app/console assetic:dump` in verbose mode (`app/console assetic:dump -vvv`) to check that you actually don't have any error when building your assets.

Why? Because sometimes assetic doesn't clear your cache correctly. And assetic also tends to hide the errors by failing transparently when you are in console mode.

Comment: Are you sure about your `node_path`?
My guess would be that you may be suffering from an environment variable issue. When running in console mode, you may have more information available.

Comment: Keep in mind that when running Assetic / Symfony from Apache / Nginx, you don't run as the same user. And most of the time, you don't have access to the environment variables that you have access to in console mode.

Keep in mind that signal 11 is related to a segmentation fault.